# Could i use http path for Client SSl Certificate when running collection using Newman Cli?

Tags: postman, ssl-certificate, newman

newman clis run module supports --ssl-client-cert option

`newman run postman_collection.json  --ssl-client-cert iis_cert_2018_07.pem --ssl-client-key iis_cert_2018_07.pem --insecure`

the --ssl-client-cert takes local filesystem path to the cert. I have a need to keep the certificate in awsS3 bucket or at some http url location to which i have full access.

questions:

1. does newman support http paths for client SSL certificates?
2. what is the alternative?  i want to run my collections using newman js lib in cloud specifically in AWS Lambda